# Shape of an array in numpy.asarray

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, slice, distance

I am trying to calculate distances of points in space using scipy.distance.cdist. A contains positions of Na points, B contains positions of Nb points.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial import distanceNa=100
Na=100
Nb=500
A=np.random.rand(Na,3)
B=np.random.rand(Nb,3)
dist=distance.cdist(A,B)
```

Will give me distances between points in A and in B. However when Na > 20000 and Nb > 500 000 this function will give Memory error. To overcome this I am trying to slice A and B into smaller chunks, calculate distances and concatenate them:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial import distanceNa=100
Na=100
Nb=500
A=np.random.rand(Na,3)
B=np.random.rand(Nb,3)
As=np.array_split(A,10)
Bs=np.array_split(B,10)
np.asarray([distance.cdist(X,Y) for X in As for Y in Bs]).shape
```

This returns (100, 10, 50). I understand the first dimension but why 10 and 50?
More interestingly if I change Na=102 then this time it will return: (100, ).
In this case my code:

```
QQ=np.asarray([distance.cdist(X,Y) for X in As for Y in Bs])
QQ.reshape(len(As),len(Bs)
JJ=[np.concatenate((QQ[i,:]),axis=1) for i in range(len(As))]
dist=np.concatenate((JJ[:]),axis=0)
```

Gives exact same matrix with distance.cdist(A,B). But if Na=100, Nb=500 shape of previous array will be (100,10,50) prevent reshaping and concatenate operations.
Is there any better pythonic way to do this? Basically my problem is cdist function gives memory error for larger arrays.

Comment: `array_split` can split the array into unequal sized arrays.  Look at `As` in the `102` case.  Look at the `[distance ...]` list (before applying `np.asarray` to it.  It will contain many arrays.  Check their shapes.  If they are all the same it makes an array with a new first dimension.  If they differ, it makes a 1d `object` dtype array.

Comment: It's a good idea to test code with small arrays.  That way you can look at results, final and intermediate, in detail.

Answer (score 0):

Your `As` and `Bs` are both length 10, so you `Z = [distance.cdist(X,Y) for X in As for Y in Bs]` has length 100.

Each of the entries in this list is a numpy array of shape 10,50 since each `X` has length `Na/10 = 10` and each `Y` has length `Nb/10 = 50`.

When you call `as_array` you get a numpy array of size `(100,10,50)` since the list `Z` just becomes axis 0 of the array.

Note that the first entry of `Z` corresponds to the first block of `As` with the first block of `Bs`. The second entry of `Z` corresponds to the first block of `As` with the second block of `Bs`. In general, the `k`-th entry of `Z` corresponds to the `Z%len(As)` block of `As` and `A//len(As)` block of `Bs`.

However, to store all of `Z` in memory will likely also run out of memory, so probably you want to save each block as you go rather than trying to reconstruct the whole thing at once.